# How can I add a border around an image figure?

Tags: typst

I would like to be able to draw a thin black border around my figure. I couldn't find a `border` option anywhere in [the `figure` documentation](https://typst.app/docs/reference/meta/figure/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that it's as simple as putting it in a default [`rect`](https://typst.app/docs/reference/visualize/rect/)!:

```
#let ekf = figure(
  rect(image("../figures/ekf.svg")),
  caption: [
    Position Error and $plus.minus 3 sigma$ Interval
  ]
)
#ekf
```

[image]